# Ошибка selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException could not be scrolled into view

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Всем привет. Пробую осваивать selenium, на данный момент удалось сделать так, чтобы происходил переход на сайт и переключение одного параметра на другой, а вот с указанием значения в поле ввода - нет.
Вот основной(проблемный фрагмент). Работаю через Firefox.
Полная ошибка: 
**selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element  could not be scrolled into view**

```
b = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@class="col span8 input_focus trade_input bg_white"]')
self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 300);")
time.sleep(10)
b.click()
b.send_keys('100')
```

основной фрагмент HTML:

```
<div class="row trade_row">
    <label class="col span4 input_label">
        <span class="input_label_valign">Количество</span> 
    </label>
    <input class="col span8 input_focus trade_input bg_white" 
    name="buyAmount" value="0" ng-keyup="recalPriblValues()" 
    autocomplete="off" type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Совершенно очевидная ошибка. Ходил вокруг да около, а дело все в том, что не обратил внимание на одинаковое название нескольких классов. Просто указал:

```
b[4].click()
```

И все заработало. Возможно кому-нибудь будет полезным